# How to add inflation to each column in the data.table in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm pretty new to Shiny and I'm currently working on a project. I am frustrated on adding some inflation to the datatable as shown below. Since I'm doing a spread in the code and I'm not sure where I should add the numericinput variable?

Please let me know if more details or clarification are needed. Thanks!

```r
#Load packages
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DT)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
library(tidyr)

periods <- data.frame(p = c(1:3), start = c(as.Date('2020-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date('2021-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'),as.Date('2022-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')),
                      end = c(as.Date('2020-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date('2021-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d'),as.Date('2022-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d')))

example<-data.frame("Provider" = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a"), "Network" = c("50k", "45k", "40k", "40k", "45k", "50k"), 
                    "AWP" = c(500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000), "Claim" = c(100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("p1_inf","Inflation Period 1", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
    numericInput("p2_inf","Inflation Period 2", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
    numericInput("p3_inf","Inflation Period 3", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
    width = 3
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("PLAN_AWP_table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$PLAN_AWP_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
   
    f<-example %>% 
      group_by(Provider, Network) %>% summarize(total_AWP = sum(AWP)) %>% as.data.frame()
    
    g<-merge(periods, f) %>% 
      mutate(new_AWP=total_AWP*10) %>% 
      group_by(p, start,end,Provider, Network) %>% 
      summarize(new_awp=sum(new_AWP)) %>% 
      as.data.frame() 
    
    PLAN_AWP<- g %>% 
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(dt_range = paste0('Period ' , as.character(p), '. ', format(start, '%m/%d/%Y'), '-', format(end, '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      select(Provider, Network,dt_range,new_awp) %>%
      spread(key = dt_range,value=new_awp,fill = FALSE) 
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2020-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Check the updated code. Columns are updated based on inputs in dropdown.

```
#Load packages
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DT)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
library(tidyr)

periods <- data.frame(p = c(1:3), start = c(as.Date('2020-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date('2021-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'),as.Date('2022-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')),
                      end = c(as.Date('2020-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d'), as.Date('2021-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d'),as.Date('2022-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d')))

example<-data.frame("Provider" = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a"), "Network" = c("50k", "45k", "40k", "40k", "45k", "50k"), 
                    "AWP" = c(500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000), "Claim" = c(100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("p1_inf","Inflation Period 1", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
      numericInput("p2_inf","Inflation Period 2", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
      numericInput("p3_inf","Inflation Period 3", 0, min = NA, max = NA),
      width = 3
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("PLAN_AWP_table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$PLAN_AWP_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    f<-example %>% 
      group_by(Provider, Network) %>% summarize(total_AWP = sum(AWP)) %>% as.data.frame()
    
    g<-merge(periods, f) %>% 
      mutate(new_AWP=total_AWP*10) %>% 
      group_by(p, start,end,Provider, Network) %>% 
      summarize(new_awp=sum(new_AWP)) %>% 
      as.data.frame() 
    
    PLAN_AWP<- g %>% 
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(dt_range = paste0('Period ' , as.character(p), '. ', format(start, '%m/%d/%Y'), '-', format(end, '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      select(Provider, Network,dt_range,new_awp) %>%
      spread(key = dt_range,value=new_awp,fill = FALSE)
    
      PLAN_AWP[3] = PLAN_AWP[3] * input$p1_inf
      PLAN_AWP[4] = PLAN_AWP[4] * input$p2_inf
      PLAN_AWP[5] = PLAN_AWP[5] * input$p3_inf
      
      datatable(PLAN_AWP)
      
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: sorry. I mean use the numeric input times the number in the year columns, which are column 3, 4, and 5. Hope it helps.